# Parsing through text with incorrect attribute definition

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xml-parsing

While trying to parse an html document as XML (added xml start at the beginning) I've ran into a problem with attribute inside tags.

```
<tr>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1" nowrap align="right">Jun 4, 2013</td>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">453.22</td>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">454.43</td>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">447.39</td>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">449.31</td>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">10,454,600</td>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">449.31</td>
</tr>
```

While normally it wouldn't matter (since my xslt code doesn't actually reference it), I am getting an error :

```
ERROR:  'Attribute name "nowrap" associated with an element type "td" must be followed by the ' = ' character.'
ERROR:  'com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: Attribute name "nowrap" associated with an element type "td" must be followed by the ' = ' character.'
```

So i was wondering if there's a way to make it suppress / ignore those errors. (Looking for a way of doing it that doesn't involve a separate parse through that would remove all nowrap first.)

(For reference, xml : http://pastebin.com/TLD4bZkq , xslt : http://pastebin.com/dPzDzeAX )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you're trying to process isn't XML, so the XML parser is right to produce an error.

Depending on what XSLT processor you're using and how you call it you might be able to use an HTML parser instead of an XML parser to parse your HTML into a DOM tree which you then pass to the XSLT processor, rather than having the processor parse the file itself.

But remember that XSLT expects namespace-well-formed XML and if the parser's output doesn't conform to this then you will have problems. For example, in Java (which is what I'm most familiar with), for a DOM Document to be usable by XSLT it must have been produced by a namespace-aware parser *even if* the document in question doesn't actually use any namespaces.

Comment: Thank you, i guess it's time to make a string parser first.